# How to solve UNIQUE_ID variable issue in modsecurity_crs_16_session_hijacking.conf ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.04, mod-security

I have been trying to harden ubuntu 10.04 using modsecurity and its core rules from owasp version 2.2.5. I have used the package from their [github](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/tarball/v2.2.5) . After the symbolic link of the files in the optional_rules to the activated_rules, apache started complaining and won't start. below is what it says:

```
Syntax error on line 45 of /etc/apache2/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_16_session_hijacking.conf:
Error creating rule: Unknown variable: UNIQUE_ID
```

Does anyone have a workaround to fix this. I have done the same thing on ubuntu 12.04 and didn't have any issue. But this time I have no control on the version of ubuntu used here. that is 10.04.

I have tried to install mod unique_id but it was already installed, mod headers as well. So I am out ideas on possible cause. A little hand would be really appreciated.

Thank you